# The horizontal navigation bar clips on the "h2" element and I want under it

Tags: html, css, position, navigationbar

I just started coding after a while so I tried the one's in w3schools and it worked after I put lorem ipsum paragraph to fill it in. It first moved the h3 next to the navigation bar, then its over the navigation bar. and it doesn't have its space.

Then I used some codes from other websites and no luck

```css
h2{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    word-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Header;
}


nav{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  padding: 13px;
}
#horBar {
  margin: 11px;
  font-family: Serif;
  width: 1000px;
}

#horBar li {
  display: block;
  width: 117px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 4px;
  border: 2px double rgb(82, 20, 20);
}

#horBar a {
  color: #006;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 4px;
  display: block;
}

#horBar a:hover {
  color: rgb(237, 124, 124);
  background-color: #006;
}
```

```html
   <nav>
      <ul id="horBar">
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="customer.html">Customer</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="orders.html">Orders</a></li>
        <li><a href="reports.html">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="administrations.html">Administrations</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>`
```

Comment: What do you want to happen on your h2/h3 and paragraph it is not clear as your code doesnt include the h3 nor h2 on it.

Comment: The h2, h3 and paragraph are inside the body element, Just in case the nav element is inside the head element. <body> <h2> Future about cars </h2> <h3>What is a future car?</h3> <p>"Lorem ipsum paragraphs"</p> </body>

Comment: I was looking in a youtube video and saw the property "margin-bottom 30px" and it helped me separate the navigation bar and h3 element. The navigation bar went above the h3 element but I wanted it under.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you mean. because your navigation is on absolute position it is separated from everything.if you position your navigation as relative then that should automatically be part of everything, or else you can put a margin on your body to position it absolute then if you want to stretch it since it is in absolute you need to move it around using left right and top. Let me know if this is what you mean.

```css
h2{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    word-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Header;
}


nav{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
   
    
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  padding: 13px;
}
#horBar {
  margin: 11px;
  font-family: Serif;
  width: 1000px;
}

#horBar li {
  display: block;
  width: 117px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 4px;
  border: 2px double rgb(82, 20, 20);
}

#horBar a {
  color: #006;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 4px;
  display: block;
}

#horBar a:hover {
  color: rgb(237, 124, 124);
  background-color: #006;
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <ul id="horBar">
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="customer.html">Customer</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="orders.html">Orders</a></li>
        <li><a href="reports.html">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="administrations.html">Administrations</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <body> <h2> Future about cars </h2> <h3>What is a future car?</h3> <p>"Lorem ipsum paragraphs"</p> </body>
```